# How can I change the number of displayed suggestions with Antd Autocomplete?

Tags: autocomplete, antd

By default Autocomplete seems to show 8 suggestions at a time, the rest you will have to scroll down to see it. There are no component property related to this number in Antd documentations. Is there any way to change that to another fixed number? How about making it display all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally Autocomplete use the component Select and make all Select properties available, even internal props. `listHeight` can be used to increase the height of the suggestion dropdrown list. As note in Antd's `Select` [documentation](https://ant.design/components/select/):

> Virtual scroll internal set item height as 32px

To make Autocomplete display 10 items for example, set `listHeight={320}` to Autocomplete. To make it display all items, pass an arbitrary large number to `listHeight` like 999999 or `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`